# Years of Service Formula in Google Sheets

Tags: date, datetime, google-sheets, concatenation, google-sheets-formula

How do I create a formula for years of service in Google Sheets?

This formula is giving me an error in Google Sheets.

```
=DATEDIF((B6,"7/10/2019", "Y")&" years")
```

[image: Screenshot of sheet]

I wish to have the output state "10 years". I also need to put the end date as TODAY, but when I input Today() as a date, the formula does not work.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=DATEDIF(B6; TODAY(); "Y")&" years"
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

Too many brackets... try

```
=DATEDIF(B6,"7/10/2019", "Y")&" years"
```